# Run Script Rule option disapperared after office upgade

Tags: vba, outlook

I had a simple but very important vba rule in Outlook.

This morning my Office upgraded to 16.0.7531.1003 version (64 bit) and 
I found my rule unchecked and trying to check it I get message "This rule is unavailable in current mode" (this is a translation as I am not using English version of Outlook).

Furthermore, the option "run script" is no longer visible while trying to configure a new rule.

The only thing the rule does is searching new email body for valid GUID, and if any exists, it inserts the GUID and email SentOn date into database.
Did Microsoft disable VBA rules at all?

```
Public Sub getGUID(receiptItem As MailItem)
Dim regE As New RegExp
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim sql As String: sql = "insert HDSDEB.dbo.ReportCalendar_received(ReportGUID, SentDatetime) values ('__GUID__', '__SentOn__');"

regE.Pattern = "[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}"
regE.IgnoreCase = True
regE.MultiLine = True
Set matches = regE.Execute(receiptItem.body)

If matches.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
Debug.Print matches.Item(0).Value

sql = Replace(sql, "__GUID__", matches.Item(0).Value)
sql = Replace(sql, "__SentOn__", receiptItem.SentOn)

SQLQueryRun (sql)
Debug.Print sql
End Sub
```

Comment: Can add the VBA code to your question?

Comment: I edited my post, but note that the code runs perferctly (a have another macro wich iterates through selected items and calls code above). The problem is that i cannot reset the rule to call this

Comment: Which Office are you using? 2013?, Have you tried using `ItemAdd Event`? better then rule script

Comment: it's 2016, seems to be a good idea, I am trying this now

Comment: Thank you, it works fine, but... ItemAdd must be bound to a collection of items, as my emails are filtered by rules and ItemAdd is triggered after rules are applied, I must watch specific folder. Problem is that this kind of code must be specific to user (different users, different rules = different folders). Is there a global collection of mails, disregarding folders?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue like yours and [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/outlook-2016-rules-start-application-option-gone/1eb0066d-d50f-4948-824e-adee58ca5a6f) may be what you need. Adding a new value to my computer's registry (`EnableUnsafeClientMailRules`) and set it to 1 solved my problem.

Comment: Pasting the contents from the link here:
1. Click Start -> Search, type ‘regedit’ (Note: there is no quotation marks in the command.) and press Enter.
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security.
3. Right-click a blank area, create a new DWORD Value named as ‘EnableUnsafeClientMailRules’ and set it to 1.
Note: Please back up the Registry before performing the steps above. You can refer to this article to back up your Registry.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I solved the problem (this and some more with Excel) by changing Ofiice Update channel from Current to Deferred. Seems to me (not mentioned anywhere in Ofiice documentation) that Current channel is kind of beta versions. Unfortunately.

Comment: MS just released an update for Outlook 2013 that required me to add this DWORD to re-enable rules to be able to Run Macros.

Comment: I have the same problem with Outlook 2013 but I don't see a "Security" key under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook.Where did you add the DWORD value? Should I create the "Security" key?

Comment: Anyone know how to change the `EnableUnsafeClientMailRules` setting on Mac?